# The Data produced by Scala Kafka Producer program can not be consumed by consumer

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

My Kafka Cluster version is 0.11.0.3

Here is my scala Code,which used to produce data to Kafka cluster:

```
val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.240:9092,192.168.0.213:9092,192.168.0.235:9092")
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,String](props)
    var counter = 0
    var keyFlag = 0
    while(true){
      counter +=1
      keyFlag +=1
      val content: String = userlogs()
      producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test2", s"key-$keyFlag", content))
      if(0 == counter%200){
        counter = 0
        Thread.sleep(2000)
      }
    }

    producer.close()
  }

  def userlogs()={
    // produce data...
  }
```

but when l run the code,the consumer doesn't consume the data.
[image]

kafka-client maven version is 0.11.0.3 too.
but the way below is useful:

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.0.240:9092,192.168.0.213:9092,192.168.0.235:9092 --topic test2
```

Comment: Start `kafka-console-producer.sh` before running the program or add `--from-beginning` property to `kafka-console-producer.sh`

Comment: Try to add `producer.flush()` in the if block